# LibGDX, вращение спрайта

Tags: java, libgdx

В игре есть спрайт

```
private Sprite planet;
```

Этот спрайт необходимо плавно вращать  вокруг своей оси
В методе render я пишу

```
planet.setRotation(90);
batch.draw(planet, 0, midPointY + 70, 136 * 1.5f, 137 * 1.5f);
```

т.е. так он должен быть повёрнут на 90 градусов, но поворота не происходит.

**Первый вопрос:** почему не поворачивает?

**Второй:** как сделать вращение?

Answer (score 0):

Использование `batch.draw` для спрайта не верно, правильно использовать `planet.draw(batch)`.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, сейчас все вращается, но сейчас происходит искажение изображения. Не подскажите как с этим эффектом побороться?

Comment: То есть искажение? Происходит ли это только с этим объектом или со всеми после добавления этой строки?

Comment: только с этим объектом